# Models doesn't appear when setting up gazebo programmatically

Tags: windows

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone,

I tried the example animated_box which setup the server with a box inside.Then I launch the gzclient,  it connect to the server and the box appears in the "models" but not on the render.
I also tried to setup other models programmatically but they don't move (it's like they're not being simulated): they don't fall down for example (gravity flag is true in the model).
Is there a way to make this work?

I'm working on Windows with gazebo 7 compiled in 32bits with Visual Studio 2013. Also unlike the tutorial I use the latest version of OGRE.

Thank you!

XB32Z

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12817/models-doesn%27t-appear-when-setting-up-gazebo-programmatically/) by [XB32Z](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2505/xb32z/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [XB32Z](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2505/xb32z/) on 2016-03-10**:
it appears when gzclient is launch before publishing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sorry for the very late answer :/
I made my own branch available here: https://bitbucket.org/XB32Z/windows_gazebo7 It hasn't been merged with the main because it doesn't compile under linux anymore. I guess that Gazebo is just not made for Windows ...

However I got it to work: launch the client before adding any models !

Thx for your help.

---

Originally posted by [XB32Z](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2505/xb32z/) with karma: 23 on 2016-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2016-04-01**:
The order of launch sounds like the right solution. Side note: we still intend to get gazebo running on Windows eventually, so we would love if you could keep that windows branch up to date with master. Even if it doesn't compile on linux, we can work that part out. Windows contributions are super helpful for us!

**Comment by [XB32Z](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2505/xb32z/) on 2016-04-08**:
Hi!
I'm planing to make something cleaner soon :)